# What is the source for RL Rivest's "reversal of defaults" quote?

Tags: privacy

I'm doing some work on computing privacy and I need to track down the source for a quote by Ronald L. Rivest which goes like:

> "reversal of 
>   defaults": what was once private is now public; what 
>   once was hard to copy is now trivial to duplicate; 
>   what was once easily forgotten is now stored forever.

This is pretty useful axiom, but I need to be able to read it in context, does anyone know where this is from, book, paper or speech?? I've searched for every combination of terms I can think of in Google, Scholar and the ACM digital library, but no one who uses this quote cites it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a citation in ["RFID Security and Privacy" by Dirk Henrici](https://books.google.com/books?id=75aVC-TvoO4C&lpg=PA33&dq=%252522what+was+once+easily+forgotten+is+now+stored+forever%252522&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q=%22what%20was%20once%20easily%20forgotten%20is%20now%20stored%20forever%22&f=false). He quotes it like this:

> Ronal E. Rivest, Whither Information
> Security?, MIT Laboratory
> for Computer Science, http://wean1.ulib.org/Lectures/Distinguished%20Lectures/2001/03.0%20Ronald%20L%20Rivest/6SLIDES/security.ppt, 2001.

The references section of Henrici's book can be found at the [publisher's website](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-79076-1) (it's the "Back Matter" PDF). Unfortunately the quoted [URL](https://web.archive.org/web/20070623092825/http://wean1.ulib.org/Lectures/Distinguished%20Lectures/2001/03.0%20Ronald%20L%20Rivest/6SLIDES/security.ppt) gives me a timeout.

**Edit**:

Here's the link Dana the Sane found: hopefully unmangled by the clever software behind this site: http://web.archive.org/web/20070623092825/http://wean1.ulib.org/Lectures/Distinguished+Lectures/2001/03.0+Ronald+L+Rivest/6SLIDES/security.ppt

Comment: Got it, although the link wouldn't work, had to use arhive.org http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://wean1.ulib.org/Lectures/Distinguished%20Lectures/2001/03.0%20Ronald%20L%20Rivest/6SLIDES/security.ppt

Answer (score 1):

Have not located the actual quote yet, but here are a couple of indirect references.
The links refer PDF files.
 <sub>(thanks for referring the quote)</sub>

---

Paper: [**A Middleware Architecture for Privacy Protection in Smart Environments**](http://www.ist-discreet.org/publications/A_Middleware%20Architecture_for_Privacy_cr.pdf) by
Eleftherios Koutsoloukas, et al. concludes with,

> Future technological reality is characterized by Ron Rivest’s **“reversal of defaults”**: what was once private is now public; what once was hard to copy is now trivial to duplicate; what was once easily forgotten is now stored forever. Thus, in this paper, a framework meeting the principles formulated by the privacy legislation and the consequent technical requirements is described.

---

Paper: [**Privacy by Design - Principles of Privacy-Aware Ubiquitous Systems**](http://www.vs.inf.ethz.ch/res/papers/privacy-principles.pdf) by
Marc Langheinrich also summarizes,

> What lies at the intersection of privacy protection and ubiquitous computing is easy to
>   imagine: the frightening vision of an Orwellian nightmare-come-true, where countless
>   “smart” devices with detailed sensing and far-reaching communication capabilities will
>   observe every single moment of our lives, so unobtrusive and invisible that we won’t
>   even notice!
>
> Ron Rivest calls this the “**reversal of defaults**”: “*What was once private
>   is now public*”, “*what was once hard to copy, is now trivial to duplicate*” and “*what
>   was once easily forgotten, is now stored forever.*” Clearly, “*something” needs to be
>   done, as nearly all work in ubiquitous computing points out, yet little has so far been
>   accomplished.*"

---

There appears to be a reference in the book **RFID Security and Privacy**, *Dirk Henrici*, **p33**.
This carries a bibliographical reference `Riv01` which I could not reach. Maybe, it is a direct citation.

Comment: Thanks, I've come across both of those I think. If necessary, I may have to resort to an indirect citation :(

Comment: I am curious to get the context. If you do find it, please note that here.

Comment: See Manni's Answer